# Parceable error : Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 1112

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, parcelable

I go to activity from two fragment and i pass extras through intent the first intent is data

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AllAlbumImgActivity.class);
        photoGrapherSavedPhoto.albumName=getResources().getString(R.string.photos);
        intent.putExtra(SELECTED_IMG_ID, photoGrapherSavedPhoto.id);
        intent.putExtra(LIST_NAME, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.photos));
        intent.putExtra(LIST_TYPE, CURRENT_PHOTOGRAPHER_PHOTOS_LIST);
        intent.putExtra(CURRENT_PAGE, nextPageUrl);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_ALBUM_IMAGES, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) photoGrapherPhotoList);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ALBUM_LIST_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and it worked fine

the second intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AllAlbumImgActivity.class);
        photoGrapherSavedPhoto.albumName="Saved";
        intent.putExtra(SELECTED_IMG_ID, photoGrapherSavedPhoto.id);
        intent.putExtra(LIST_NAME, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.saved));
        intent.putExtra(LIST_TYPE, CURRENT_PHOTOGRAPHER_SAVED_LIST);
        intent.putExtra(CURRENT_PAGE, nextPageUrl);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_ALBUM_IMAGES, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) photoGrapherSavedPhotoList);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ALBUM_LIST_REQUEST_CODE);
```

but it doesn't work fine with second intent data

here is how i receive the data

```
     if (intent.getSerializableExtra(LIST_TYPE) != null)
            photosListType = (Constants.PhotosListType) intent.getSerializableExtra(LIST_TYPE);

        if (intent.getStringExtra(LIST_NAME) != null)
            topBarTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra(LIST_NAME));

        if (photosListType == CURRENT_PHOTOGRAPHER_PHOTOS_LIST || photosListType == CURRENT_PHOTOGRAPHER_SAVED_LIST) {
            nextPageUrl = intent.getStringExtra(CURRENT_PAGE);
        }

        if (intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_ALBUM_IMAGES) != null) {
            this.albumImgList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ALL_ALBUM_IMAGES);
            int selectedPosition = intent.getIntExtra(SELECTED_IMG_ID, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < albumImgList.size(); i++) {
                if (albumImgList.get(i).id == selectedPosition) {
//                    Objects.requireNonNull(allAlbumImgRv.getLayoutManager()).smoothScrollToPosition(allAlbumImgRv, null, i);
                    scrolledPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

but when i pass the second intent it shows this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.softmills.phlog, PID: 14899
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.softmills.phlog/com.example.softmills.phlog.ui.album.view.AllAlbumImgActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b21b847: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 1100
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@b21b847: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274595 at offset 1100
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2747)
    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:3098)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2319)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2689)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3037)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:1227)
    at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1034)
    at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:7516)
    at com.example.softmills.phlog.ui.album.view.AllAlbumImgActivity.initView(AllAlbumImgActivity.java:97)
    at com.example.softmills.phlog.ui.album.view.AllAlbumImgActivity.onCreate(AllAlbumImgActivity.java:85)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

there i was passing All album as parceable and in the two intent it has the same object

but one work and one generate strange error related to parcelable!!

Answer (score 0):

You can trying this one :

```
#Parcel
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Add this to proguard , it can be help u.